# What is the formula for calculating time in and time out?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I am creating a spread sheet where I have just time in B2 and time out B3.  I have it in the 09:00:00AM format.  I want to get the total of hours worked in cell C, but I am not having any luck with the formulas. Can you please help me out? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Formula to calculate total number of hours worked:

`=B3-B2`

Then format the cells displaying the total number of hours worked as follows:

[image]